# Including the model value as a string type while calling functions in thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, web, thymeleaf

I am new to thymeleaf.Now i am struck in a simple block while using thymeleaf.Actually i have to call a Javascript function something like this,

```
<input type="button" onclick="function1('myvariable')">
```

I have stored the value in a model with attribute named "attr".while accessing i tried code something like this,

```
 <input type="button" th:onclick="${'function1('+attr+')'">
```

Now the problem which occurs here is i am not able to perform onclick function since the value which comes inside onclick is

```
<input type="button" onclick="function1(myvariable)">
```

and it gives an Javascript error "myvariable" is not defined.It would get solved once the symbol single quote comes inside the function1.I donno how to do it.Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to escape your single commas inside your literals with `\'`:

```
<input type="button" th:onclick="${'function1(\''+attr+'\')'">
```

Disclaimer, per StackOverflow rules: I am thymeleaf's author.

**UPDATE**: If using Spring EL, it should be:

```
<input type="button" th:onclick="${'function1('''+attr+'''')'">
```

Comment: No Its not working too.I tried it like th:onclick="${'function1(\''+attr+'\')'}".But it gives me an error "unexpected escape character"

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right. If you are using Spring, and that is a Spring EL expression, you should escape your single quotes with `''` and not `\'`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jstl tag libs you can export your attribute in the scope of your page using :

```
<c:set var="myvariable" value="${attr}" />
```

and use it in your code :

```
<input type="button" onclick="function1(myvariable)">
```

I hope it may help you

Comment: No ..Its not working.It says "could not parse the expression function1(myvariable)"

Comment: Oup's i forgot the quotes around myvariable, can you try it ? i update the post to add this.